# How to configure Maven for a single codebase but multiple artifacts

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jar, maven-shade-plugin

I have a single very large codebase that compiles down to a JAR. I also use the shade plugin to compile it down and package it up with all dependencies. I also use the war plugin to get a WAR file.

With respect to the WAR file, once the goal is created I have a post-build event that simply copies the WAR file to its destination, so technically I'm good with that.

The problem I have is with the other two JARs. They both share the same artifactId since they're both built in a single pom.xml and this isn't acceptable for a number of reasons (including, but not limited to the fact that some caching of dependencies is pretty dumb about realizing that one JAR is the thin one and one is the full-dependency one).

What I need to do is create a pom.xml (or group thereof) suitable for builds (by Jenkins) that can use the same codebase (pulled from Github) but create two separate JAR files, each with their own artifactId.

Being a Maven novice, I've read through the beginning book and it seems to me that what I want is a parent pom.xml with two modules. But from what I can tell, each module means a separate directory with separate code. As I said, this is built from the same codebase. The only difference is one is built from the "regular" build, and the other is built using the "shade" plugin and goal.

The only other thing I can think of is build the "regular" JAR and then build the shaded JAR with a classifier of "full?" If this is the answer, may I humbly ask for some adult supervision on how to do this, as I'm not seeing how.

If that's not the answer, I suspect this must be a common problem, so again, some guidance would be very helpful!

Comment: You should build your "thin" jar in one maven project and make two additional projects that depend on this one. The "full-dependency"-jar is one of the depending projects, the war is the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to use a classifier for the "shaded" jar. Thus, the artifacts don't collide.

I then had an issue accessing it, but found the solution to that issue as well - [How do I access a jar with a classifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145858/how-do-i-access-a-jar-with-a-classifier/24146192#24146192)